# if lambda function inside a VPC can access the Elastic search in same VPC without the AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-elasticsearch

Is this possible that AWS lambda service inside a VPC can access the elasticsearch service inside a same VPC without applying AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole? I don't know whether its possible or not? Please tell me the procedure if any one know.

Answer (score 2):

To access resources within your VPC you need to specify subnets and/or security for your lambda-function as described in the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html?shortFooter=true#vpc-configuring).

Subnets determine the VPC and AZ your function will be run in (or at least where its Elastic Network Interface - ENI will be created). The associated security groups determine, ports of other resources in your VPC can be accessed.

As to your AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionPolicy the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/intro-permission-model.html) states:

> **AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole** – Grants permissions for Amazon
>   Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2) actions to manage elastic network
>   interfaces (ENIs). If you are writing a Lambda function to access
>   resources in a VPC in the Amazon Virtual Private Cloud (Amazon VPC)
>   service, you can attach this permissions policy. The policy also
>   grants permissions for CloudWatch Logs actions to write logs.

I don't have access to my account currently, but google tells me that the policy document looks something like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "logs:CreateLogGroup",
        "logs:CreateLogStream",
        "logs:PutLogEvents",
        "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
        "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
        "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

This means that the Policy grants the permission to **create** the aforementioned Elastic Network Interface in your VPC and as such **would be necessary**, because without a Network Interface inside the VPC you can't get access to these private resources.

Comment: Where should i attach this policy?

Comment: This policy needs to be added to the Lambda Execution Role for your function.

Comment: So i have to create this policy as a one role in IAM then this role should added to the lambda function. am i right?

Comment: Just curious why this `AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole` role has the `ec2:CreateNetworkInterface` permission to get access to resources in VPC, does it mean a lambda function is actually running on EC2 instance?

Comment: @cifer Yeah, more or less - many services are built on top of EC2 instances. Lambda uses [Firecracker MicroVMs](https://firecracker-microvm.github.io/) that run of the same machines that power EC2 to host the functions.

Comment: I added VPC, subnets and security group to lambda of elastic cache. then, I added these policies in IAM role statements of user of lambda application, but I am still not able to access elastic cache from lambda.